# IndexError: list index out of range-QGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I Try to make plugin in qgis and I have a problem. Below is my code:

```
destination_layer =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Destination')[0]
matrix =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('join')[0]

for f in matrix.getFeatures():
    origin_expr = QgsExpression('Site Name={}'.format(f['Site Name']))
    destination_expr = QgsExpression('Site Name={}'.format(f['Site Name_2']))
    origin_feature = origin_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(origin_expr))
    origin_coords =  [(f.geometry().asPoint().x(), f.geometry().asPoint().y())
        for f in origin_feature]
    destination_feature = destination_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(destination_expr))
    destination_coords =  [(f.geometry().asPoint().x(), f.geometry().asPoint().y())
        for f in destination_feature]
    params = {
        'INPUT':'NCR Road',
        'START_POINT':'{},{}'.format(origin_coords[0][0], origin_coords[0][1]),
        'END_POINT':'{},{}'.format(destination_coords[0][0], destination_coords[0][1]),
        'STRATEGY':0,
        'ENTRY_COST_CALCULATION_METHOD':0,
        'DIRECTION_FIELD':'',
        'VALUE_FORWARD':'',
        'VALUE_BACKWARD':'',
        'VALUE_BOTH':'',
        'DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,
        'SPEED_FIELD':'',
        'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,
        'TOLERANCE':0,
        'OUTPUT': 'Shortest Path Layer' }
    print('Executing analysis')
    processing.runAndLoadResults("qneat3:shortestpathpointtopoint", params)
```

Then when I run my code, it show this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why it is not working in plugin?

Comment: What is unclear to you about the error message? Did you identify which list and which index it is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

We need more information like which code is on line 90? Anyway I would double check and making sure your index is doing correct things

```py
'START_POINT':'{},{}'.format(origin_coords[0][0], origin_coords[0][1]),
'END_POINT':'{},{}'.format(destination_coords[0][0], destination_coords[0][1]),
```

And

```py
destination_layer =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Destination')[0]
matrix =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('join')[0]
```